# Optaplanner Curriculum example, Explanation for curriculumCourseScoreRules.drl

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm currently reading the course curriculum example of optaplanner and I can't seem to understand this:

```
rule "conflictingLecturesSameCourseInSamePeriod"
    when
        // line 1
        Lecture($leftId : id, $leftCourse : course, $period : period, period != null)
        // line 2
        Lecture(course == $leftCourse, period == $period, id > $leftId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

Questions are:

- What's the difference between the Lecture() in line 1 and the Lecture in line 2? 
- I understand the variable assignements are happening in Line 1 but in Line 2, what's the difference between `course` and `$leftCourse`, `period` and `$period` and `id` and `$leftId`

So far, I can't seem to find any explanation in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binding such as `$leftCourse : course` establishes `$leftCourse` as a variable that refers to the field `course` of a `Lecture` object.

The lecture in line 1 is identified by its `id`; the one in line 2 has an id that is greater. Assuming that `id` values are primary keys, this combination would basically match all possible unordered pairs of Lectures, but ...

... the constraint `course == $leftCourse` restricts the pairings to those of identical courses and ...

... the constraint `period == $period` furthermore restricts it to equal (non-null) periods.

In other words, the planning rules out an assignment for two different Lectures for the same course in the same period.

Comment: So that's saying that given **any** two Lecture objects, there should not be two that has the same course and period, right?

Comment: also, is it correct to assume that optaplanner "remembers" which Lectures are in conflict because of this line? `scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);`

Comment: Should be "yes" to both - otherwise the rule would be rather pointless. There are ways to get at the actual fact objects participating in a rule firing "behind the scenes", which can be done in that call to addHardConstraintMatch.